# Data sources tab is missing in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I started reading the Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4 and I'm having the following problem here with my visual studio 2010

I can't find the data sources tab page as mentioned here:

> When you open the Data Sources window in Visual Studio, you will
>   find that a data source has
>   already been created for each domain context created by RIA Services
>   in the Silverlight project, with the entities that they expose beneath
>   them (as shown in Figure 6-2). Dragging and dropping one of these onto
>   your design surface will create both a DomainDataSource control and a
>   bound control to display the data.

I know that the Data Sources window and Data menu are intentionally disabled in Websites and Web Application Projects but my project is a Silverlight business application.

Can someone tell where i can find this window or what should i do to create the DomainDataSource control and the bound control?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the 'Data' menu isn't visible?

Comment: @StevenJeuris it is but there is no option for the Data Source window..

Comment: For me "Data" isn't a menu item.  It's only there for certain (undocumented) types of projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have MainWindow.xaml open, the DataSources tab is normally right next to the Toolbox tab.

[image]

If it does not appear there, go to View -> Toolbars, and turn on the Data Design toolbar.  Click the Show Data Sources button.

[image]

Or just use Shift + Alt + D

Answer (score 0):

When I create an empty project, I am able to access Data Sources as follows:

- Select a project in the solution explorer. (Not a solution!)
- The 'Data' menu on the menu bar now allows you to access the data sources for this project, along with other Data Source related options.

Comment: I have yet to see a "Data" menu item on the menu bar.  Shift+Alt+D brings up "Data Sources" in some projects, but not all (and it's not clear how you tell which will or won't).

Comment: @HotLicks Just checked, I have it in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, with sub-menus 'Transact-SQL editor' and 'Schema view' in a project without data sources. It isn't there in Visual Studio 2013 Professional. Don't know where it comes from or how to use it any more, but I wasn't hallucinating when I answered this. ;p

Comment: Yeah, it's all over the map.  I have VS 2012 and about 40% of the time when a tutorial tells me to select a given menu option it's not there.  It's an Adventure game.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got a workaround. For some reason, it only shows up if you do a Silverlight project. So I started a blank solution, added a silverlight project. Bingo - there is the Data Source window. Now, add whatever project you really need.

Comment: My VS2010 says that I can't make a Silverlight project, because I need the Silverlight Developers, but when I want to install it it says I have it already installed. Like wtf mrkvosoft..

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build the project that contains your objects before the objects appear in the tree view.

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

You can find this toolbar option in View -> Other Windows -> Data Sources or use

**Shift + Alt + D**

[image]